# Filling an area above a curve with many colors (matlab, surf)

Tags: matlab, colors, surf

I'm trying to create a figure in matlab that looks like this:
[desired figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIyPz.png)

I am doing so by: (i) assigning value points to each x,y coordinate, (ii) plotting a surf, and (iii) change the view point so the third axis is not seen. Here is the code:

```
    x = linspace(0, 1, 10);
    y = linspace(0, 1, 10);
    z = linspace(0, 1, 10);
    z = repmat(z, 10, 1);
    z = flipud(triu(z));
    z(z==0) = nan;

    hold off
    surf(x, y, z, 'linestyle', 'none')
    colormap([linspace(0.39, 1, 20)',linspace(0.58, 0.25, 20)', linspace(0.93, 0.25, 20)']);
    colorbar
    xlim([x(1) x(end)])
    shading interp
    view([90 -90])
    hold on
    plot(x, 1-y, 'linewidth', 2)
```

I get the following figure: [matlab figure I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRlES.png)

As you can see, there a lot of white spaces above the line which I would like to be in color as well. Unfortunately, I cannot add any more grid points as calculating the actual value of the points takes a lot of time (unlike the example above).

Is there a way to have matlab draw colors in those white spaces as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `patch` function to create filled polygon.
See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html

Try the following code:

```
vert = [0 1;1 1;1 0]; % x and y vertex coordinates
fac = [1 2 3]; % vertices to connect to make triangle
fvc = [1 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 1];
patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceVertexCData',fvc,'FaceColor','interp');
```

Result is close:
[image]

---

I was managed to get closer to the desired figure:

```
close all

x = linspace(0, 1, 10);
y = linspace(0, 1, 10);

%colorbar
xlim([x(1) x(end)])

%Fill rectangle.
vert = [0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1]; % x and y vertex coordinates
fac = [1 2 3 4]; % vertices to connect to make squares
%patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceColor','red')
fvc = [1 0 0; 0.6 0.7 1; 0.6 0.7 1; 1 0 0]; %Color of vertices (selected to be close to example image).
patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceVertexCData',fvc,'FaceColor','interp')
hold on

%Fill lower triangle with white color.
vert = [0 0;0 1;1 0]; % x and y vertex coordinates
fac = [1 2 3]; % vertices to connect to make triangle
fvc = [1 1 1; 1, 1, 1; 1, 1, 1]; %White color
patch('Faces',fac,'Vertices',vert,'FaceVertexCData',fvc,'FaceColor','interp');

plot(x, 1-y, 'linewidth', 2)

set(gca,'Xtick',[],'Ytick',[]); %Remove tick marks
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Rotem! I wasn't aware of the patch function and indeed it solved the issue!
The colors on the actual figure I'm trying to achieve are not linear, so I just used patch for all the empty triangles. Here is the adjusted code I use for the simple example (again, this is just a bit more general just to be able to have non linear colors in the area above the curve):

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 10);
y = linspace(0, 1, 10);
z = linspace(0, 1, 10);
z = repmat(z, 10, 1)+0.1;
z = flipud(triu(z));
z(z==0) = nan;
z = z-0.1;

hold off
surf(x, y, z, 'linestyle', 'none')
colormap([linspace(0.39, 1, 20)',linspace(0.58, 0.25, 20)', linspace(0.93, 0.25, 20)']);
colorbar
xlim([x(1) x(end)])
shading interp
view([90 -90])
hold on

patch_cor_y = kron((length(y):-1:1)', ones(3, 1));
patch_cor_x = kron((1:length(x))', ones(3, 1));
patch_cor = [y(patch_cor_y(2:end-2))', x(patch_cor_x(3:end-1))'];
patch_path = reshape(1:length(patch_cor),3,  length(patch_cor)/3)';

patch_col = z(sub2ind(size(z), patch_cor_x(3:end-1), patch_cor_y(2:end-2)));

patch('Faces',patch_path,'Vertices',patch_cor,'FaceVertexCData',patch_col,'FaceColor','interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none');

plot(x, 1-y, 'linewidth', 2)
```

The figure achieved: [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg3Bt.png)